Supervised vs. Unsupervised Learning Outlier Detection with Existing Labeled Data
I am working on a software project that processes sensor measurement data. These data often contain outliers, which are currently manually evaluated and labeled (outlier or not) by domain experts. A significant amount of labeled data is available, and the goal is to automate the outlier detection process using machine learning.
I have read that unsupervised learning methods are well-suited for outlier detection because they group data points into clusters and identify points outside these clusters as outliers. However, given the availability of labeled data, supervised learning seems like a natural choice.
Could you provide a technical explanation or comparison to help determine whether supervised or unsupervised learning would perform better for this application, especially considering the availability of labeled data?
